# SASS starting, doing math with variables

Tags: variables, sass

I'm starting with SASS but I can't figure how to do proper math with a variable.

Here is my code:

```
$page-width: 1200;
margin-left: 50% - ( ( $page-width / 2 ) + px);
```

I tried so many versions but they're all wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this math you have to mix `%`and `px`and it gets done using `calc` operations with CSS.

```
$page-width: 1200;

.element-class{
  margin-left: calc(50% - (#{$page-width}px / 2));
/* outputs: margin-left: calc(50% - (1200px / 2)); */
}
```